# Optimizing VBA command to delete rows with blanks

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro where I use the following command to delete all rows where A = blank:

```
Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

The files that I am running through this macro range from 1kb to 300mb.

Doing some pressure testing, it appears that when the file is below 15mb, the command will execute almost instantaneously, resulting in a 20 second to 6 minute run time for the macro.

The second I plug in a file that is larger than 15mb, the macro will get caught on this command for 30-40 minutes.

Does anyone have a nifty trick to optimize this command for large files? If it takes a fraction of a second for a 13mb file, there must be a way to make it take a fraction of a second for a 15mb file and hopefully make it take a fraction of a second for a 300mb file...

Comment: Are you turning off screenupdating and setting calculation to manual?

Comment: Was looking into screenupdating as you were typing that out. I dont think setting calculation to manual would make a difference. There are no formulas present when the command is running.

Comment: Can you sort the data? It's the abstract arrangement of the rows to be deleted that is gumming up the works.If they can all be sorted so that blank column A cells are in one contiguous block at the bottom of the data matrix everything will go much faster.

Comment: To do that, id need to add in an index, and if I do that, then the rows wont truely be blank and will make the file larger, which is what I am trying to avoid... the file size bloat may be worth the time it buys though...

Answer (score 0):

Use an [AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and temporarily turn off all possible environment parameters.

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
            .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
            .AutoFilter
        End With
    End With
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

It has been my experience that even looping through the rows from bottom to top can sometimes beat a call to delete [Range.SpecialCells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) with the [xlCellTypeBlanks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx).

Comment: Okay, I plugged this in, and the difference appears to be negligible. It may end up being better overall, but ive been running for 15 minutes and its still going, which is exceeding what I was hoping for. At that rate, id just keep the simpler command and leave it running overnight, Though I still dont want to do that...

Comment: Did you get the `.Cells.Sort` modification I included?

Comment: Copy and pasted your code and changed the worksheet name.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so, basically riding on Jeeped's suggestions that sorting is the best method to do it, I just decided to index the data and sort:

```
'Insert column for index
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

'Apply index
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"

Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[1]="""","""",R[-1]C+1)"

Range("A3:A" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=IF(RC[1]="""","""",IF(R[-1]C="""",R[-2]C+1,R[-1]C+1))"

'Sort blanks to bottom
Columns("A:Z").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterList").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterList").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Columns( _
    "A:A"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Masterlist").Sort
    .SetRange Columns("A:Z")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

Columns("A").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Which runs like butter. Leaves the non-true-blank rows at the bottom, which is going to drive up the file size a bit, which is not ideal, but id rather run the macro run fast and take a half Meg penalty in file size than sit here waiting 40 minutes when I want to run a large file.